# Can I simply connect two AC/DC converters for increased current?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

There is [this product](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1682154.pdf?_ga=1.12683127.1507173468.1470864157), an AC/DC converter which is capable of outputting 5V at 600mA. I have a circuit which might draw as much as 1000mA. Can I simply use two of these converters together with the outputs connected in parallel? What do I need to be aware of?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Connecting the outputs directly is not a good idea as there will always be a small voltage difference between the two. What happens then is that they will "fight" each other and whichever has the lower voltage will act as a current sink for the other. The crude solution is to put a diode in line with each of the outputs to prevent current flow back into the supplies. Unfortunately this introduces a voltage drop of approx 0.7V across the diode.

It's possible to run two supplies but you'll either want to divide the system such that each supply powers separate parts, or use a single larger supply.

Comment: Not all converters have both active source and sink circuitry. A standard DC-DC buck or boost converter, for instance, will have only a high-side FET providing source current, and sinking is done passively by the load discharging the output capacitors. I'd even go so far as to say that your characterization is almost always wrong. That doesn't mean that the combination will work, only that I'm dubious about your explanation.

Comment: A Schottky diode has a smaller voltage drop (~0.1v-0.45v depending on current) than a standard silicon diode. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_diode

Comment: For a *real low* voltage drop, you can use a power path controller as LTC4412.